# How do I root a Samsung Galaxy Star Duos S5282?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-star-duos

How do I root my Samsung Galaxy Star Duos S5282? How do I put it in recovery mode?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you tried searching for this? There is a how-to [right over here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2378158) on the XDA Developers forum.

Comment: Also, this is actually two questions. If you have more than one question, please keep them separate. I would also recommend searching the internet for instructions for both questions - feel free to come back here if you have trouble.