# Root Galaxy Star Pro

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-star-duos

Is there any tutorial for rooting Galaxy Star Pro (S7260). With rooting package ? I bought this phone recently and I could't find a tutorial for rooting this phone by googleing.

Comment: Is that the same device as the [Galaxy Star Duos S5282](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/56411/16575)? I doubt it from your question, but the tag is suggesting it :)

Comment: not S5282. It is S7260.

Comment: And that's called "Galaxy Star Duos"? Or did you just chose the "closest tag"? // Btw: I've linked to your question from our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575), which you might wish to consult for "general info" (Generic rooting methods and the like), while waiting for an explicit answer.

Comment: try this app first [Kingoroot](http://kingoapp.com/). Works for most :D

Answer (score 0):

<sup>based on the link given by [satyam's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/61504/16575), which now is dead</sup>

A guide was available at tricksdroid.com (the domain went down in 2015, so it's dead now), the page can still be [found at Archive.Org](http://web.archive.org/web/20140220064852/http://www.tricksdroid.com/2013/12/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-star-pro.html?). The essentials summed up in short:

#### Requirements

- USB drivers for the device (or Samsung Kies)
- [usb-debugging](/questions/tagged/usb-debugging) enabled on the device
- The Galaxy Star Pro should be factory unlocked and not locked to any particular carrier.
- Have a recent backup available in case things go wrong.
- Ensure the battery of the device is charged more than 80 percent.
- Verify the model number of the Galaxy Star Pro by selecting Settings >> About Phone.
- [CWM recovery](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2428988&d=1386015992)
- [SuperSU](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu)
- [Odin 3.07](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1722686)

#### Procedure

1. Extract the Odin 3.07 and CWM Recovery files using winrar/7zip/winzip or any other extracting tool
2. Copy the UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.75.zip file to the SD card of your phone
3. Switch off the Galaxy Star Pro. Then boot the device into Download Mode by pressing and holding <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons together until a construction Android robot icon with a warning triangle appears on screen. Now press the <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> button to enter Download Mode.
4. Run Odin on the computer as an Administrator.
5. Connect the Galaxy Star Pro to the computer using USB cable while it is in the Download Mode. Wait until Odin detects the device. When the device is connected successfully, the `ID: COM` box will turn to light blue with the COM port number. Additionally, the "successful connected" will be indicated by a message saying "Added".
   Note: If the Added message does not appear, then try re-install USB drivers or changing the port on the computer.
6. In Odin, click the PDA button and select the `recovery.tar.md5` file. Verify that Auto Reboot and Re-Partition options are NOT selected.
7. Double-check and click Start button in Odin. The installation process will now begin.
8. Once the installation process completes, you will see a "PASS" message with green background in the left-most box at the very top of the Odin. You can now unplug the USB cable to disconnect it from the computer.
9. Reboot the device into CWM Recovery by pressing and holding <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons together.
10. In CWM Recovery, select "install zip from sdcard" and then select "choose zip from sdcard". Now, navigate to the `UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.75.zip` file that you copied earlier and confirm the installation by selecting "Yes".
11. Once installation process is completed, return to main recovery menu and select "reboot system now".