# Regarding root of my device samsung galaxy star pro gt S7262

Tags: rooting

i cant root my device   after using odin drivers too
my problem is in recovery mode it is not showing the option install from zip
it is showing only 4 options they are 1 .reboot device  2. install update from adb  3. factory reset   4. wipe cache partition 
 so plz help how could i root my device

Comment: Related: [Root Galaxy Star Pro](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/58874/16575). PS: The only answer until a few minutes ago contained nothing but a dead link. I've tracked that to Archive.Org and posted a new answer, please check out.

Comment: You're probably still using the stock recovery. Check [TWRPRecovery v2.6.3.0 Star Pro | Plus GT-S7262](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-star/development/twrp-team-win-recovery-project-v2-6-3-0-t3114966) and follow the steps precisly!

Comment: @benjaminS thanx a lot.... my device was nw rooted

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, I'll make an answer out of it. If it solved your issue you may wish to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are really facing is that you are still using the stock recovery. Flash a custom recovery.

---

With credits to **ItsAnilSingh** from xda-developers. He is the [**creator of the recovery and posted the installation steps**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-star/development/twrp-team-win-recovery-project-v2-6-3-0-t3114966).
[image: Install-Insctructions]